# Count based on Grouping and Dynamic Range in LINQ

Tags: c#, performance, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a requirement to get grouped data and the counts based on the ranges.
This isn't the actual scenario, but it's a similar, simple case of what I need to do:

```
public class ProductSale{
 public long ID {get; set;}
 public long ProductID {get; set;}
 public DateTime SaleDate {get; set;}
 ...
}

public class Product{
  public long ID {get; set;}
  public long ProductCategoryID {get; set;}
  public string Description {get; set;}
  ...
}

public class ProductCategory{
  public long ID {get; set;}
  public string Description {get; set;}
  ...
}

public class ProductSaleRange{
 public long ID {get; set;}
 public long Range{get; set;}
}
```

this ProductSaleRange table has data 
1:4,  2:9, 3:15

which compute as sale ranges 0-4, 5-9, 10-15 and 15+

As per above structure, we need to generate report of sale between date ranges which will be look like
     ProductCategoryName|Total Count of Products Soled in the Given Date Range|product sold 0-4 times| productsold 5-9 times| product sold 10-15 times |product sold 15 + times

these ranges are dynamic and coming from Productsale range table.
I need generate reort using C#/Linq to get result in above format 
the result is groupbing by Productcategory , the total products sold in the category and count of products those are sold in the range.
Say there 18 products in a category, 76 total sales happens of these 15 products, out 3 products were sold 6 times , 2 were sold 11 times and no one sold above 15 times
so my report look like

[image]

i have achived total count by grouping ProductSale by ProductCategoryID  and for ranges i am looping productSale for each range for each category.
i want to remove looping as this is not giving fast results, i need to implement in better best way to get these result using Linq.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

UPDATED

Here is my code till now

```
public static IEnumerable<ProductSaleRanges> GetGetProductSale(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        using (var db = new Entities())
        {
            var sales= db.ProductSale.Where(x =>  x.SaleDate  >= startDate && x.SaleDate  <= endDate).ToList();
            var result = (from r in sales= 
                          group r by r.Product.ProductCategoryID  
                         into g
                         select new ProductSaleRanges
                                    {
                                        ID = g.Key.ToString(),
                                        ProductCategory= ..,//fetch name
                                        ProductSaleRanges=GetSaleRangesByCategory(sales , g.Key)
                                    }).ToList();
            return result;
        }

    }
public static List<ProductSaleRangesByCategory> GetSaleRangesByCategory(IEnumerable<ProductSale> sales, Int64 categoryid)
    {
        var productList = (from s in sales
                                where s.Product.ProductCategoryID  == categoryid
                                group s by s.ProductID
                                    into sg
                                    select new ProductList { ProductID = sg.Key, SaleCount = sg.Count() }).ToList();
        var result = GetSaleRangeDetails(productList );
        return result;
    }

 public static List<SaleThreshold> GetSaleRangeDetails(IEnumerable<ProductList > productList) 
    {
        int minCnt = 0;
        int maxCnt = 0;
        int cnt = 0;
        var model = ProductSaleRange.GetProductSaleRange().ToList();//returns all sale ranges from DB
        var listLength = model.Count;
        var index = 0;

        var result = model.Select(x =>
        {
            string text;
            if (index == listLength - 1)
            {
                minCnt = (x.Range);
                maxCnt = 365;       //days in year

                cnt = GetSaleCount(productList, minCnt, maxCnt);
                text = x.Range.ToString() + "+ Times";
            }
            else
            {
                minCnt = (x.Range + 1);
                maxCnt = model[index + 1].Range;
                cnt = GetSaleCount(productList, minCnt, maxCnt);
                text =
                    (x.Range + 1).ToString() + "-" + (model[index + 1].Range).ToString() + " Times";
            }
            index++;
            return new SaleThreshold
            {
                ID = x.ID,
                Intervals = text,
                Sale= cnt,
            };
        }).ToList();

        return result;
    }

public static int GetSaleCount(IEnumerable<ProductList> productList, int minCnt, int maxCnt)
    {
        int cnt = productList.Where(x => x.SaleCount  >= minCnt && x.SaleCount  <= maxCnt)
            .Select(x => x.ProductID).Count();

        return cnt;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us what you did so far ? How are you computing these results at the moment for the example shown ? It's complicated to translate this into Linq if we don't know what you're actually doing.

Comment: Hi Matt i have added my code